# Directly render pdf from urllib with out saving the file and then make it downloadable in django

Tags: python, django, pdf, urllib2

I always used to save the files I wanted to make downloadable in django. In my project I used that code ***for example:***

```
def keyDownload(request, benutzername):
        benutzernameKey = benutzername +".key"
        fsock = open('/var/www/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/'+benutzernameKey, 'r')
        response = HttpResponse(fsock, mimetype='application/pgp-keys')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename = %s " % (benutzernameKey)
        return response
```

I got a pdf file which I get through urllib:

```
url = "http://www.urltomypdf.com"
sock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
with open('report.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    while True:
        content = sock.read()
        if not content: break
        f.write(content)
```

At the moment I am saving the pdf in a file called report.pdf. But my aim is to render it directly to my template with a function in django. Is that possible ?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/outputting-pdf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the introduction of Django 1.5, the `StreamingHttpResponse` class has been made available to stream a response based on an iterator. Your view and iterator could look like this:

```
def stream_pdf(url, chunk_size=8192):
    sock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    while True:
        content = sock.read(chunk_size)
        if not content: break
        yield content

def external_pdf_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    url = <url> # specify the url here
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(stream_pdf(url), content_type="application/pdf")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "filename='%s'" % <filename> #specify the filename here
    return response
```

Pre Django 1.5, it is still possible to stream a response by passing an iterator to `HttpResponse`, but there are several caveats. First, you need to use the `@condition(etag_func=None)` decorator on your view function. Secondly, some middleware can prevent a properly streamed response, so you'll need to bypass that middleware. And finally, a chunk of content only gets send when it reaches a length of 1024 bytes, so `chunk_size` should be over 1024.

Comment: That should do the trick, given that you've set the correct mimetype and headers etc.

Comment: It seems a chunk size of 1024 is quite small, a chunk size of 8192 (8KB) seems to be much more common. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just like you did in your question :) I'll update my answer with a complete example.

Comment: Can you post a full traceback?

Comment: What's the value of `url` in your view?

Comment: And what's the exact result of `type(url)`?

Comment: Okay I just removed request.GET.get() and it worked :D